# Appending numpy array to class list changes the shape of class list

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, time-series

I start with my train and test sets. They are NumPy arrays.

Then I create a variable history = x for x in train. This is a class list.

For i in range len(test), I do a forecast. In this forecast() function, history is made into an array with the shape (30, 72, 7) then flattened to (2160, 7). Within the loop, before the iteration goes to next step, test is appended to history as so: history.append(test[i, :]).

When the iteration runs the next time, it stops when trying to run forecast() again because the array history has the shape (31,) and cannot be flattened.

I am suspecting that either the types are the problem or the history.append(test[i, :]). But which is it? And how do I fix the problem?

Here are the relevant functions:

```
# evaluate a single model
def evaluate_model(train, test, n_input):
  print("ENTERED EVALUATE_MODEL!")
  # fit model
  model = build_model(train, n_input)
  # history is a list of weekly data
  history = [x for x in train]
  print("HISTORY TYPE after declaration: ", type(history))
  # walk-forward validation over each week
  predictions = list()
  for i in range(len(test)):
    print("Test.shape(): ", test.shape)
    print("Round: ", i+1)
    # predict the week
    yhat_sequence = forecast(model, history, n_input)
    print("yhat_sequence type: ", type(yhat_sequence))
    # store the predictions
    predictions.append(yhat_sequence)
    # get real observation and add to history for predicting the next week
    #test = np.array(test)
    # print("TEST SHAPE :", test.shape)
    print("TEST ", test)
    print("History ", history)
    print("HISTORY TYPE BEFORE APPEND: ", type(history))
    print("TEST TYPE BEFORE APPEND: ", type(test))
    history.append(test[i, :])
    #test = test.tolist()
    print("TEST after: ", type(test))
    print("HISTORY after: ", type(history))
  # evaluate predictions days for each week
  predictions = array(predictions)
  score, scores = evaluate_forecasts(test[:, :, 0], predictions)
  return score, scores

# Make a forecast.
def forecast(model, history, n_input):
  print("forecast()")
  # flatten data
  data = array(history) #History is entered again each time. But for the second round this is (31,) in shape...
  print("data(history) shape in forecast(): ")
  print(data.shape)
  data = data.reshape((data.shape[0]*data.shape[1], data.shape[2])) #...so then this reshape doesn't work.
  print(data.shape)
  # retrieve last observations for input data
  # For multivariate, make sure to use all features.
  input_x = data[-n_input:, :]
  # reshape into [1, n_input, 1]
  # We need to change the shape as well to take all features.
  input_x = input_x.reshape((1, input_x.shape[0], input_x.shape[1]))
  # forecast the next week
  yhat = model.predict(input_x, verbose=0)
  # we only want the vector forecast
  yhat = yhat[0]
  return yhat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a list (of lists or arrays) that can be turned into a

```
(30, 72, 7)
```

array.  The only thing you can add to that list is a

```
(1, 72, 7)
```

shape array, which will make a (31, 72, 7) array.

Anything else will result in a (31,) object dtype array (or an error).  And if the `numpy` is new enough I'd also expect a "ragged array" warning.

So when checking `shape` also check `dtype`.

Comment: So many thanks for a simple straightforward answer! My only question is what you mean with "if the numpy is new enough"?

Comment: It looks like test has the shape (30, 4 ,7) after my data split and reshape. Which I presume isn't right then. Before the reshape it's (148, 7). Any tips on how to tackle this?